# jQuery difference between FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

He guys, why does this code work on Chrome, but not on FF?

The alert below is blank in FX but gives me the RGB color in Chrome

```
jQuery.each(menuids, function(index, value) { 
        var allclass = jQuery('#'+value).attr('class');
        if( (allclass.split('current-menu-item')).length > 1){
                var currentURL = window.location.href;
                var allhtml = jQuery('#'+value).html();
                var allhtml_arr = allhtml.split('href="');

                var allhtml_arr1 = allhtml_arr[1].split('">');

                if( allhtml_arr1[0] == currentURL ) {
                    var allclass_arr = allclass.split(value);
                    var current_colorcls = jQuery.trim(allclass_arr[1]);
                    jQuery('ul#primary-menu').addClass(current_colorcls);

                    var prop = jQuery('ul.'+current_colorcls).css('border-top');
                    var prop_arr = prop.split('solid');
                    var current_colorcode = jQuery.trim(prop_arr[1]);
                    alert(current_colorcode);
                    jQuery('.crg-theme-color').css('color',current_colorcode);
                    jQuery('.site-info').css('border-top', '3px solid '+ current_colorcode);
                }
            }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which line/part of code does not work. Any console errors?

Comment: In Chrome `alert(current_colorcode);` alerts a colour, in FX it seems to be empty

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to get the color of the selected menu item and assign it to the class .crg-theme-color

Comment: Actually I don't care about WHY if someone can suggest a workaround, but if someone figures it that would be impressive!

Comment: Can you console.log your findings from the top - starting with allclass

Comment: Does the `'border-top'` behave in a different way in FF? Check this line `var prop = jQuery('ul.'+current_colorcls).css('border-top');` with debugger.

Comment: Yeah I found the same. In FF `jQuery('ul.Atlantis.css('border-top');` is blank

Comment: Try using shorthands `css('borderTop')`

Comment: Actually borderTop was ALSO not enough. borderTopColor is the full name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems there is an [issue in FX-jQuery about shorthand](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13421). Border-color is still too short. You can get the color using the full name:

```
var prop = jQuery('ul.'+current_colorcls).css('borderTopColor');
```

Example

```
console.log(jQuery('ul.Atlantis').css("borderTopColor"))
```

gives me `"rgb(167, 204, 61)"`

PS: To get a list of all classes you can do this in newer browsers

```
$(element)[0].classList
```

There is a [shim for older browsers here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)